# save result of get_absolute_url in django model Field

Tags: django

I want to save result of post.get_absolute_url() in my Django model as Field.

```py
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post_detail', args=[self.publish.year,
                       self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])
```

For example:
`absolute_url = models.CharField(...'result of post.get_absolute_url()'...)`.

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the models save method. This will be run every time the model is saved.

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    absolute_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.absolute_url = self.get_absolute_url()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```